# unable to load dashboard page after login codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a controller  `al.php` , when I am trying to load the dashboard page which is written in `dashboard()` method, it shows me a blank page. please help me I am new to codeigniter.

```
function dashboard() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('al_login') != 1)
        redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
    $page_data['page_name']  = 'dashboard';
    $page_data['page_title'] = get_phrase('al_dashboard');

    $this->load->view('backend/index', $page_data);
    //$this->load->view('backend/al/dashboard', $page_data);
}
```

if I give like this it loads the page with data all over without css.

```
$this->load->view('backend/al/dashboard', $page_data);
```

Comment: Be more specific to your question

Comment: You are not able to load css is this your question?

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this...

```
 function dashboard()
    {
        if (!$this->session->has_userdata('al_login'))
            redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
        $page_data['page_name']  = 'dashboard';
        $page_data['page_title'] = get_phrase('al_dashboard');

        $this->load->view('backend/index', $page_data);
   //  $this->load->view('backend/al/dashboard', $page_data);
    }
```

`$this->session->has_userdata('al_login');` returns FALSE if the 'al_login' item doesn't exist or is NULL,

See here https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html

Save your ai controller as `Ai.php` and if you want to redirect to `dashboard` method of Ai controller..then try to load like this

```
$this->load->view('al/dashboard', $page_data);
```

Comment: it loads the   $this->load->view('backend/index',)index page with data problem i guess with $page_data

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: i want to load the    $page_data['page_name']  = 'dashboard'; like this

Comment: you want to load it in backend/index view page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should need to check first your function is calling correctly or not?

Like below:

```
function dashboard() {
    exit;
    if ($this->session->userdata('al_login') != 1)
        redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
    $page_data['page_name']  = 'dashboard';
    $page_data['page_title'] = get_phrase('al_dashboard');

    $this->load->view('backend/index', $page_data);
    //$this->load->view('backend/al/dashboard', $page_data);
}
```

If correct, Please check your index page is located at correctly else check there is any statement has died or not.

Because your function is i think correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
function dashboard(){
  if ($this->session->has_userdata('al_login') != ''){
      redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');          
  }
       $this->load->view('backend/index', $page_data);
}
```

If is not working then please check ur session data or view file.